# Why is my onclick event throwing undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
```

And the following JavaScript right below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  function printDiv(divName) {
   alert('s')
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML
     w=window.open()
     w.document.write(printContents)
     w.print()
     w.close()
  }
})
</script>
```

When I click printDiv, though I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: printDiv is not defined payment-history:398
>   onclick

I really don't get it.

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html if you want to learn more about event handlers.

Answer (score 6):

Because `printDiv` is not in global scope. You have wrapped it with a function. So, `printDiv` scope is within that immediate function and not global.

[JavaScript scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)